# Multiple WHERE functions in SQL

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm trying to write an SQL query to return information including product code, yearly sales revenues, costs, sales people information from two different tables. I need to return the product ID information for the product with the lowest'onboarding cost' for the 'north' region.

I have used `WHERE Region = 'North'` to just get the product info for the North region, and `ORDER BY onboarding cost;` to sort this low to high and find the product with the lowest cost. Is there a way of just returning the product with the lowest onboarding cost for the north region?

Comment: You need the JOIN ON condition. Please add your SQL

Comment: You should GROUP BY the non-cost columns and then SELECT MAX(cost)

Comment: When using MySQL, you can use [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html), when using MSSQL you can use [TOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: SQL added above

Answer (score 1):

In the WHERE clause you could add:

... AND onboarding cost=(SELECT MAX(onboarding cost) FROM ... WHERE region='North' ...)

```
 SELECT 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.ProductID, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear2,  
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear2, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OnboardingCost, 
 SalesPeople.FirstName, 
 SalesPeople.LastName, 
 SalesPeople.Region
FROM SalesPeople INNER JOIN ProductRevenueAndCosts ON 
SalesPeople.SalesPersonID = ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID
WHERE SalesPeople.Region = "North" 
AND ProductRevenueAndCosts.OnboardingCost=(
   SELECT MAX(ProductRevenueAndCosts.OnboardingCost)
   FROM SalesPeople INNER JOIN ProductRevenueAndCosts ON 
   SalesPeople.SalesPersonID = ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID
   WHERE SalesPeople.Region = "North"
)
ORDER BY ProductRevenueAndCosts.Onboardingcost DESC -- this is obsolete
;
```

But this will eventually return more than one result - in case that more than one product has the same highest onboaring cost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to limit the number of records, like this:

## MySQL, PostgreSQL

```
SELECT 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.ProductID, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear2,  
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear2, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OnboardingCost, 
 SalesPeople.FirstName, 
 SalesPeople.LastName, 
 SalesPeople.Region
FROM SalesPeople INNER JOIN ProductRevenueAndCosts ON 
SalesPeople.SalesPersonID = ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID
WHERE SalesPeople.Region = "North"
ORDER BY ProductRevenueAndCosts.Onboardingcost DESC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Where 0 is the starting index (first row) and 1 is the number of records you want to get.

## SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.ProductID, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear2,  
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear2, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OnboardingCost, 
 SalesPeople.FirstName, 
 SalesPeople.LastName, 
 SalesPeople.Region
FROM SalesPeople INNER JOIN ProductRevenueAndCosts ON 
SalesPeople.SalesPersonID = ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID
WHERE SalesPeople.Region = "North"
ORDER BY ProductRevenueAndCosts.Onboardingcost DESC;
```

Where `TOP 1` tells the RDBMS that you are interested only in the very first row.

## Oracle

```
SELECT 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.ProductID, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesRevenueYear2,  
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear1, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OperationalCostsYear2, 
 ProductRevenueAndCosts.OnboardingCost, 
 SalesPeople.FirstName, 
 SalesPeople.LastName, 
 SalesPeople.Region
FROM SalesPeople INNER JOIN ProductRevenueAndCosts ON 
SalesPeople.SalesPersonID = ProductRevenueAndCosts.SalesPersonID
WHERE SalesPeople.Region = "North"
ORDER BY ProductRevenueAndCosts.Onboardingcost DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```